# API call to directory.members.insert failed with error: Member already exists

Tags: google-apps-script

I am automating onboarding using a google app script in a google sheet. I want to add members to multiple groups. The code I have works but only for one user(the first user on the sheet). How can I make it so that the code loops through the entire sheet and not stop after the first user?

```
function addNewMember() {

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet Name")
    var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues()

  for(i=1; i <values.length; i++)
  {

    var groupArray = ["group1@example.com", 
 "group2@example.com"];
    var userEmail = values[i][6];
    var member = {
    email: userEmail,
    role: 'MEMBER'
  };

  for (i in groupArray){

   AdminDirectory.Members.insert(member, groupArray[i]);
    Logger.log('User %s added as a member of group %s.', userEmail, groupArray[i]);
  }

}
  }
```

I get this error: API call to directory.members.insert failed with error: Member already exists.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your admin directory line in a try catch

```
try{
AdminDirectory.Members.insert(member, groupArray[i]);
    Logger.log('User %s added as a member of group %s.', userEmail, groupArray[i]);
}
catch(e){Logger.log(userEmail+" was already in group "+groupArray[i]);}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Change the name of you counter variable your second `for` loop.**

Your second loop is nested inside the first loop. Using and iterating through `i` in both of them results in an error.

```
    for(j in groupArray)
  {
   AdminDirectory.Members.insert(member, groupArray[j]);
    Logger.log('User %s added as a member of group %s.', userEmail, groupArray[j]);
  }
```

This works for me.